# Countif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If you take Column U and look at values 4, this has five 5 phases (numbers 1-5). The 3rd phase is unsuccessful, meaning that (in the new column created) I want every phase after the 3rd of that projectID to be equal to 0.

An example of what i want is below:

I attempted this and feel i am close, but not quite there.

=IF(COUNTIFS($U$3:$U$300,$U33,$AA$3:$AA$300,">="&$AA33,$AB$3:$AB$300,0)>0,0,1)

Any recommendations would be wonderful!!! Thanks

```
U AA AB My new column

2 1 1 0

2 1 0 0

2 2 0 0

3 1 1 1

3 2 0 0

4 1 0 0

4 2 1 0

4 3 0 0

4 4 1 0

4 5 1 0

4 5 0 0
```

u: projectID

AA: phase of project

AB: success/not for individual projects (0=unsuccessful; or 1 = successful)

new column: success/not for individual projects (taking into account phase of project)

Comment: Do you mean `=--(COUNTIFS($U$2:U2,U2,$AB$2:AB2,0)=0)` or really `after` the first occurance of `0`? In the latter case use `=--(COUNTIFS($U$1:U1,U2,$AB$1:AB1,0)=0)`

Comment: Just a few questions for understanding: What’s the rule/reason that there is 2 1 1 and then 2 1 0 as in 2 separate lines? The same with 4 5 1 followed by 4 5 0 ? You refer to 4 3 0 to set anything after also to 0 in the new column but there is already/still 4 1 0, what’s the rule here? (effective starting with phase 3 only?)

Comment: p.b this is really close! I changed one cell reference to reflect closely to what i'm after =--(COUNTIFS($U$1:U1,U1,$AB$1:AB1,0)=0)      The only thing is that (as you can see in the data table above) in the first two rows where U and AA  match... in this circumstance the new column would be a 0 for both of them as a 0 appears in column AB for one of the values. I think this is part of the complexity...  In the actual data i can have 10 duplicated U and matching AA values, where the AB column  could be a mix of 1's and 0's... i will play around with it. May just be a simple if statement after

Comment: UPDATE: i added a new column and used the following formula to do the above... thankyou everyone for contributing, you all really helped me out with this. it's definitely not straightforward, so i appreciate the guidance                                                                      =--(COUNTIFS(U5:U18,U5,AA5:AA18,A5,L5:L18,0)=0)
L5:L18 is the input of the column from p.b’s formula

Comment: `=(COUNTIFS($U$1:U1,U1,$AB$1:AB1,0)=0)*(COUNTIFS(U:U,U1,AA:AA,AA1,AB:AB,0)=0)`

Comment: If there are those duplicates with mix of 1 and 0, what is the rule to decide which one to choose? Probably you are already aware of: there are MAXIFS  and MINIFS as well

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Going via pseudo-code:
If this (new line reading down) is a new project
then result = success-of-this-first-phase.
else if result-so-far-of-this-project is 0
.......then 0
.......else success-of-this-phase
to the formula entered into AD2:
=IF(U2<>U1,AB2,IF(AD1=0,0,AB2))
and copy down

Gives the result you show except that in the first row is 1 rather than 0
.
Which I think is what you want?